# What is the difference between Apache Impala and Cloudera Impala?

Tags: impala

I'm a little bit confused by Apache Impala and Cloudera Impala. Is there any big difference between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloudera donated Impala to Apache at Nov, 2015. They are just different names of the same project. If you decide to use Impala, you should try the Apache one since it's being actively maintained.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Amos!